# Initializing LSTM layer with initial inputs for hidden layers

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Currently, I am working on the implementation of Learning to Generate Product Reviews from Attributes  by Li Dong (https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/E17-1059/)

I am able to write the encoding layer but not able to understand how the values from the encoding layer can be passed to the LSTM decoding layer. (for this using Keras)

Section 3.2 in the paper. 
"Once the input attributes are encoded to the vector a ∈ RLn by Equation (3), the encoding vector is split into L vectors to initialize the hidden vectors of the ﬁrst time step in the decoder"